# Where clause over multiple rows, GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, aggregate

I have the following table structure

```
AccountID   Property            Value
123456      Status              Active
123456      City                Los Angeles
123456      RegistrationDate    2018-05-11 11:30:14.000
543210      Status              Active
543210      City                Las Vegas
543210      RegistrationDate    2018-05-11 11:13:14.000
888888      Status              Inactive
888888      City                Toronto
888888      RegistrationDate    2015-05-12 11:13:14.000
```

I want to be able to Select all rows where Property == Status and Value == Active And Property == RegistrationDate and Value == 2018-05-11 11:30:14.000

Im figuring I need to do some kind of GROUP BY and then select on that aggregation but I can't get my head around it(my sql is really rusty).

I want the following output for the above "query"

```
AccountID    Status    RegistrationDate
123456       Active    2018-05-11 11:30:14.000
543210       Active    2018-05-11 11:30:14.000
```

If all the columns had existed on the same row I would just write something like this:

```
SELECT AccountID FROM Property
WHERE Status = 'Active'
AND RegistrationDate = '2018-05-11 11:30:14.000'
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40296781/mysql-select-from-tables-based-on-multiple-rows/40297059?noredirect=1#comment67852325_40297059 It's for MySQL, but the same approach should work in any SQL database.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The design pattern is called EAV ([entity-attribute-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)). It's usual to need either `GROUP BY` or queries with multiple joins with this design:

```
SELECT
      a.AccountID               
FROM 
      tbl AS a
      JOIN tbl AS b
      ON a.AccountID = b.AccountID
WHERE
      a.Property = 'Status' 
  AND a.Value    = 'Active'

  AND b.Property = 'RegistrationDate' 
  AND b.Value    = '2018-05-11 11:30:14.000' ;
```

Answer (score 6):

Another way to express this is to use `PIVOT` to convert the EAV structure to tabular form. Given:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.EAV;

CREATE TABLE dbo.EAV
(
    AccountID integer NOT NULL,
    Property varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    Value sql_variant NULL
);

INSERT dbo.EAV
    (AccountID, Property, [Value])
VALUES
    (123456, 'Status', CONVERT(sql_variant, 'Active')),
    (123456, 'City', CONVERT(sql_variant, 'Los Angeles')),
    (123456, 'RegistrationDate', CONVERT(sql_variant, CONVERT(datetime, '2018-05-11 11:30:14.000', 121))),
    (543210, 'Status', CONVERT(sql_variant, 'Active')),
    (543210, 'City', CONVERT(sql_variant, 'Las Vegas')),
    (543210, 'RegistrationDate', CONVERT(sql_variant, CONVERT(datetime, '2018-05-11 11:13:14.000', 121))),
    (888888, 'Status', CONVERT(sql_variant, 'Inactive')),
    (888888, 'City', CONVERT(sql_variant, 'Toronto')),
    (888888, 'RegistrationDate', CONVERT(sql_variant, CONVERT(datetime, '2015-05-12 11:13:14.000', 121)));
```

An example query is:

```
SELECT
    P.AccountID,
    P.[Status],
    P.City,
    P.RegistrationDate
FROM dbo.EAV AS E
PIVOT (MAX([Value]) 
    FOR Property IN 
    (
        [Status], 
        [City], 
        [RegistrationDate])
    ) AS P
WHERE 
    P.[Status] = CONVERT(sql_variant, 'Active')
    AND P.RegistrationDate = CONVERT(sql_variant, CONVERT(datetime, '2018-05-11 11:30:14.000', 121));
```

Result:

> ```
> AccountID | Status | City        | RegistrationDate   
> --------: | :----- | :---------- | :------------------
>    123456 | Active | Los Angeles | 11/05/2018 11:30:14
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=67c9b3fe009b87cbe2dac1390d4f306b)*